# Counting a Word in a Text with REGEX

Tags: c#, regex

Hello :) I have to find all words in a given text with the following restrictions:

Matching should be case-insensitive. Not all matching substrings are words and should be counted. A word is a sequence of letters separated by punctuation or start/end of text. The output should be a single integer number.

I have already solved it with StringComparison and a for-loop.

The code below is my attempt to do it with REGEX(C#).
It only gives me the count of the pattern word, but it is not aware for the restrictions.

Could you give me some tips on how to improve my REGEX pattern?

```
string patternWord = Console.ReadLine();
string[] inputSentence = Console.ReadLine().Split();
int count = 0;
string pattern = @"(?:\b\w+\ \s|\S)*" + patternWord + @"(?:\b\w+\b\ \s|\S)?";
Regex rx = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
for (int i = 0; i < inputSentence.Length; i++)
{
    var mc = rx.Matches(inputSentence[i]);
    foreach (Match m in mc)
    {
        count++;
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("{0}", count);
```

EDIT:

Example:

Input word - 
hi

Input sentence - 
Hidden networks say **“Hi”** only to Hitachi devices. **Hi**, said Matuhi. **HI**!

I only need the bold ones.

EDIT 2:
I have edited the restrictions as well.

Comment: Since matching is case insensitive it might be useful to convert the entire string to upper or lower case chars. But by no means do I know regex, maybe regex wouldn't care.

Comment: sorry I didn't understand well your restriction, can you please add an example?

Comment: why can't you use just this simple regex `\b\p{L}*\b`? Then to get final wordcount you can use `inputSenteces.Sum(x => regex.Matches(x).Count)` instead of for loop.

Comment: @A.B - example:
pattern word - hi;
sentence - Hidden networks say **“Hi”** only to Hitachi devices. **Hi**, said Matuhi. **HI**!
I need only the ones in bold.

@ Iale - I'm learning right now and I'm not very much familiar with c#, regex and LINQ :)

Comment: Isn't it sufficient to use `@"\b" + patternWord + @"\b"`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about a simple word-break regex?

```
\bhi\b
```

[image]

In C# this would be implemented like this:

```
private static int WordCount(string word, string text)
{
    var regex = new Regex(string.Format(@"\b{0}\b", word), 
                      RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    return regex.Matches(text).Count;
}
```

Comment: Than you and @Jerry very much!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for not answering your exact questions, but why use regex? LINQ and a few utility methods from the Char class should suffice for this:

```
using System.Linq;

public class Test
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string patternWord = Console.ReadLine();
        string inputSentence = Console.ReadLine();
        var words = GetWords(inputSentence);
        var count = words.Count(word => string.Equals(patternWord, word, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
        Console.WriteLine(count);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static IEnumerable<string> GetWords(string sentence)
    {
        while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sentence))
        {
            var word = new string(sentence.TakeWhile(Char.IsLetterOrDigit).ToArray());
            yield return word;
            sentence = new string(sentence.Skip(word.Length).SkipWhile(c => !Char.IsLetterOrDigit(c)).ToArray());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm curious how can I solve it with REGEX :) I have already solved it with .Split(char[])+ string.Equals + StringComparison + for-loop.